# App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, Facebook UI Changes

Tags: android, facebook-login

Wait, before **you mark it as duplicate** or something, let me clear you one thing, **I can not find the actual link or page where I can enable my app for general public,** since all the available answer are **deprecated** because **facebook has changed its layout a lot since then**, please someone help, I'm just being irate via this.

**What I did**
I already registered my email to the facebook basic settings.

Now please I'm loosing my **precious development time** for this nonsense.

Comment: I don't quite get your idea. You mean your Android App has problem? or the Facebook App?

Comment: It was showing App still in development upon registering from android app which implemented facebook auth, anyway problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

**Fill the privacy url in facebook basic settings**,

Then click on in **development switch,** then choose your app category, **enable it,**

You are done.